# Laravel - Get users name from ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.6 app that is logging various information into a database table,  I am then displaying this data in a HTML view. I am calling this view like this...

```
$logs = Log::all();
return view('logreport.index')->with('logs', $logs);
```

The table only contains the user ID, is there a way to get the users first name and last name for the users table? Or do I need to set a relationship up?

Comment: Relationships are definitely where you need to look, the best starting point would be: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships.

Comment: did you made any relation if yes please share ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the log table contain the user_id and you want to get user name you can get the user name through relation as the following:

in log model add the following method:

```
  public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
 }
```

and then you can access the user information in view file such as firstname as the following

```
  @foreach($logs as $log)
       <h1>{{$log->user->first_name  .' '.$log->user->last_name }}</h1>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Perfect, just read up on relationships and all makes sense now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set a relationship. Just use eloquent.

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', array(...))->get();
```

Or with query builder

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', array(...))->get();
```

Replace the dots by the values of your IDs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) as answered by [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672272/7109362) or you can use "**[Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)**" with your result as:

```
$logs = Log::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'logs.user_id')->get();
return view('logreport.index')->with('logs', $logs);
```

and then access the result as:

```
<h1>{{ $log->first_name .' '. $log->last_name }}</h1>
```